# Is there a QPointer specialization for boost::bind

Tags: c++, qt, boost-bind, qpointer

`boost::bind` handles `boost::shared_ptr` the same way as raw pointers.

```
QObject * object(new QObject);
boost::shared_ptr<QObject> sharedObject(new QObject);

bind(&QObject::setObjectName, object, _1)( "name" );
bind(&QObject::setObjectName, sharedObject, _1)( "name" );
```

I would love to have a `boost::bind` that handles **`QPointers`** as raw pointers pointer.

```
QPointer<QObject> guardedObject(new QObject);    
// i want to write it like this
bind(&QObject::setObjectName, guardedObject, _1)( "name" );
//now i have to do it like this
bind(&QObject::setObjectName, bind(&QPointer<QObject>::data, guardedObject), _1)( "name" );
```

Is there anyone who has made the specialization for `QPointer`?

If not do you know where to start or what needs to be specialized, so I can do it myself.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? The documented QPointer class in version 4.5 doesn't have a get method. From the looks of it your desired syntax should work...

Comment: Sorry get is for lambda/shared_ptr, for QPointer it is data

Comment: Template Argument Deduction means that QPointer<T> arguments have their type deduced as QPointer<T>, even if they have an operator T*() const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding this overload of the [`get_pointer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/boost/get_pointer.hpp) function should do the trick:

```
namespace boost {
    template<typename T> T * get_pointer(QPointer<T> const& p)
    {
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a specialization, it's an overload, which has slightly different resolution rules. Important to remember if you mix both (which you shouldn't, really). See Herb Sutter: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm